# How to pass a JSON string variable from ASP.NET to other applications?

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0

In my webapplication I need to pass a string variable using JSON. But it doesn't work... My code is:

```
string Token=builder.ToString();
var userdetails = {"token": Token};

Response.Write(userdetails);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JSON serializer, such as the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
string Token = builder.ToString();    
var userDetails = new { token = Token };
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(userDetails);
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write(json);
```

The generated output will look like this:

```
{"token":"some token value"}
```